# Regular expression help generate links

Tags: php, regex, phpbb

I currently have the following code in a loop:

```
$message = preg_replace("/({$data[0]})/i","<a href=\"{$data[1]}\" class=\"postlink\">$1</a>",$message,1);
```

The point of this loop is to look for specific keywords ($data[0]) and to turn them into links to the URL in $data[1]. I am also using a limit of 1.

This works OK to some extent. However I am trying to improve this regular expression to prevent issues such as:

- if a URL actually contains a flagged keyword, things get messed up. For example if "test" is a keyword and the page has a link to a URL like "http://www.site.com/test.html", then it will replace "test.html" which is wrong. It should ignore it.
- if the text already contains something like `<a href="blabla">this is a test</a>` , I don't want the keyword "test" to be replaced, since it's already part of a link.

Those are 2 the main issues that I've caught so far, there may be more. I'm looking for help writing a better regular expression to avoid those issues.

Thanks

Comment: For the first issue, probe for surrounding whitespace. Context-sensitive regex matching is a bit more complicated; so for the latter problem it might make sense to use a second preg_replace_callback for filtering out the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are fun. To use, just replace "test" with your data in the pattern below.

```
/test(?![^><]*?(?:>|<\/a))/
```

Edit: Updated the pattern.

In response to your comment, use the following:

```
$message = preg_replace("/({$data[0]}(?![^><]*?(?:>|<\/a)))/i","<a href=\"{$data[1]}\" class=\"postlink\">$1</a>",$message,1);
```

Comment: Parentheses are supposed to save a variable for later use - I see here that you use a couple of parentheses, isn't it conflicting with it?

Comment: Also I'm not sure which characters need to be escaped or not ... So far it crashes

Comment: It turns out PCRE doesn't support variable width lookbehind patterns, so I changed the pattern to just use lookaheads.

Comment: Could you help me fit it in with the pattern described in the question? That is, how to capture the keyword, and also make sure it's case-insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

This simply checks that there is either the begining of the line, or a space before the keyword, and an end of string, or space after the word:

```
 $message = preg_replace("/(^|\s)({$data[0]})($|\s)/mi","$1<a href=\"{$data[1]}\" class=\"postlink\">$2</a>$3",$message,1);
```

That should solve both your problems.

Comment: would it solve <a href>this test works</a> where "test" is the keyword? I think it would still create a link within a link no?